# is there a backend for recline.js built to work with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

Recline.js seems a great tool to display data on grids, maps, etc.

I'd like to use the grid views, but to be able to save what is displayed to the user on a database. I'm currently using rails for this project.

In the docs, they say how to code a backend to integrate with it (http://okfnlabs.org/recline/docs/backends.html) but i  wonder if there's already someone working on it ( I couldn't find it on the web)

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to see Active Record support.

Answer (score 1):

The `Backend` object in Recline.js a javascript component that talks to a data source of some kind, typically a web service. The Backend component talks to the interface of that web service, and it doesn't care whether it be programmed in Ruby, COBOL or Java, as long as it knows where to get and send the data, and in what format.

So in short there isn't, and can't really be a ready Rails backend, because the implementation depends more on the specifics of your application -- how to map the data in your database (MySQL?) to a service API Recline can understand, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOLR with Rails, so I dont know why you couldn't utilize the Recline.js SOLR functionality to search your rails data.